# Does clearing the cache only clear your cache on a multi-user device?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, motorola-moto-g-4g

I share a *spare* phone with my other half. I have just come to install an app on it and been unable to, due to lack of space. Looking in *Storage* I can see 400MB of *Cached data* but when I attempt to clear it, nothing happens.

I presume that these 400MB are being taken up by cached data in her user account rather than mine, thus I cannot clear it.

Is there anything I can do to clear up this device without waiting for her to come home and do the tidy up herself?